# Changing labels in a XML using Powershell based off condition

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, loops

Sample XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Searchable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" label="$RESX('Bank.1_8','CRDM_AgeInformation','Age Information')" xmlns="http://sysrepublic.com/Secure/4.0/DSL/SearchService">
  <Parameters />
  <Fields>
    <Field data-type="System.Int64" is-editable="true" id="ageinformation_transactionid" label="$RESX('Bank.1_8','TransactionID','Transaction ID')" is-mandatory-display-field="false" is-hidden-display-field="false" is-virtual-date-time="false" is-display-field-only="false" use-utc-datetime="true" apply-user-timezone-offset="false" show-date="true" show-time="true" is-favourite="false" common-field="true">
      <FieldDescription primary-key="false" nullable="false" readonly="false" hidden="false" format="text" enable-required-validation="true" />
      <Operators>
        <Operator name="equal" />
        <Operator name="notequal" />
        <Operator name="greaterthan" />
        <Operator name="greaterthanequal" />
        <Operator name="lessthan" />
        <Operator name="lessthanequal" />
        <Operator name="between" />
        <Operator name="notbetween" />
        <Operator name="in" />
        <Operator name="notin" />
      </Operators>
      <LeftExpression>
        <Field data-type="System.Int64" common-field="true">
          <CollectionDescription collection="pos.CRDM_AgeInformation">
            <Relationship parent="pos.CRDM_Header">
              <RelatedField from="TransactionID" to="TransactionID" common-to-field="true" />
              <RelatedField from="TradingDay" to="TradingDay" common-to-field="true" />
            </Relationship>
          </CollectionDescription>
          <Description>TransactionID</Description>
        </Field>
      </LeftExpression>
    </Field>
    <Field data-type="System.Int64" is-editable="true" id="ageinformation_checkpointid" label="$RESX('Bank.1_8','CheckPointID','CheckPoint ID')" is-mandatory-display-field="false" is-hidden-display-field="false" is-virtual-date-time="false" is-display-field-only="false" use-utc-datetime="true" apply-user-timezone-offset="false" show-date="true" show-time="true" is-favourite="false">
      <FieldDescription primary-key="false" nullable="false" readonly="false" hidden="false" format="text" enable-required-validation="true" />
      <Operators>
        <Operator name="equal" />
        <Operator name="notequal" />
        <Operator name="greaterthan" />
        <Operator name="greaterthanequal" />
        <Operator name="lessthan" />
        <Operator name="lessthanequal" />
        <Operator name="between" />
        <Operator name="notbetween" />
        <Operator name="in" />
        <Operator name="notin" />
      </Operators>
      <LeftExpression>
        <Field data-type="System.Int64">
          <CollectionDescription collection="pos.CRDM_AgeInformation">
            <Relationship parent="pos.CRDM_Header">
              <RelatedField from="TransactionID" to="TransactionID" common-to-field="true" />
              <RelatedField from="TradingDay" to="TradingDay" common-to-field="true" />
            </Relationship>
          </CollectionDescription>
          <Description>CheckPointID</Description>
        </Field>
      </LeftExpression>
    </Field>

</Fields>
</Searchable>
```

**Problem to solve for:**

1. Check if the XML Label used on different fields exists in a database table.
2. If it does exist, do nothing.
3. If it does not exist, change the node label. The middle value within () should be replace by the node ID. After that, if the replaced value has a underscore, replace it with a dot
4. Send over the updated value to the test table setup in the database

Below is the code I have tried:

```
$SQLServer = "WIN-17V7QT0IJVK"
$SQLDBName = "Test"
$uid ="WIN-17V7QT0IJVK\Administrator"
$pwd = "letmebackinplease"
$ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True;"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString
$SqlConnection.open()

$xml = New-Object XML
$n = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2.xml"
$xml.Load($n)
$nodes = $xml.Searchable.Fields.Field
# $regex =  '()\(.*?\)'
$regex =  '\((.*)\)'
foreach($node in $nodes) {
    $a = $node.label
    $a -match $regex
    $data = $Matches[1]
    $z = $data.split(',')
    Write-Output($z[0])
    Write-Output($z[1])
    Write-Output($z[2])

    $query = "
     SELECT
        count(ID) as cnt
     FROM [Secure4].[secure].[Resource]
     WHERE
        [ResourceType] = " + $z[0]
    $query += " AND [ResourceKey] = " + $z[1]
    $query += " AND [ResourceValue] = " + $z[2]

    Write-Output($query)
    $Resource = (Invoke-SQLCmd -query $query -Server $SQLServer)
    Write-Output($Resource)
    $id = $node.id
    Write-Output($id)
    #$description = $node.Description
    #Write-Output($description)

    if($Resource -eq '0'){
        #$id = $node.id
        #Write-Output($id)
        #$description = $node.description
        #$mid_value = $id.replace('
        $new_label = "$RESX('Ebr.Crdm.Store.2_0',"+$id+",'XXXXXX')"
        $node.label = $new_label



    }
    Write-Output($node.label)
}
```

It appears on debugging my code, I am not able to update the label correctly. Can someone please suggest the best way to change that. On running the code, I do not see the $node.label printed out.

**Problems**:

1. Do not see $node.description print in my output (SOLVED)
2. Do not see the $node.label printed out after updating it within the IF block

Comment: @vonPryz I made it short to make it more clear. Please have a look and let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: It appears I am not referencing the description variable correctly which might most likely be causing the issue

Comment: @JamesZ Thank you for editing my question. The edit looks really good

Comment: I have figured the correct way to reference it is : "$nodes = $xml.Searchable.Fields.Field.LeftExpression.Field" which means I have to make changes to my loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how your IF block should be written:

```
if($Resource -match '0'){
        $mid_value = $id -replace "_","."
        $new_label = "$RESX(Ebr.Crdm.Store.2_0,"+$mid_value+","+$description+")"
        $node.label = $new_label
        Write-Output("The updated label is"+$node.label)

        $b = $node.label
        $b -match $regex
        $newdata = $Matches[1]
        $y = $newdata.split(',')
        Write-Output("The first updated element of the node label is"+" "+$y[0])
        Write-Output("The second updated element of the node label is"+" "+$y[1])
        Write-Output("The third updated element of the node label is"+" "+$y[2])
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO [Secure4].[secure].[Resource]
               ([ResourceType],[CultureCode],[ResourceKey],[ResourceValue])
               VALUES
                    ('"+$y[0]+"','en','"+$y[1]+"','"+$y[2]+"')"
        Write-Output($insert_query)
         $Resource2 = (Invoke-SQLCmd -query $insert_query -Server $SQLServer) 
         #write-output($Resource2)

    }
```